# Which program allows remote management of Android devices?

Tags: android, remote-control, administration

I have 50 Android tablets. I want to be able to control from a central place the following things on the devices:

- General settings like date-time, unlock method, display sleep time etc;
- Chrome specific things like clearing the history and cookies, saving bookmarks, setting the homepage etc;
- the ability to install or uninstall apps on particular device or all of them;

So I need a mini SCCM for Android. Is there such a thing?

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/56857/which-program-allows-remote-management-of-android-devices).

Comment: Sorry, won't do that again. One question: if I post on one site and don't get answera, am I allowed to post the same question on another site?